# curses: how to find the height of written text area

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I created a `pad` in `curses` then I filled it with a bunch of text. the height of the pad is constant, however, I would like to know how many lines there are in the written part of the pad or the height of it.

```
rows, cols = std.getmaxyx()
text_win = cur.newpad(rows*3, cols)
text_win.addstr("some stuff")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by inspecting the result from [getyx](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getyx):

```
rows, cols = std.getmaxyx()
text_win = cur.newpad(rows*3, cols)
text_win.addstr("some stuff")
cury, curx = text_win.getyx()
used_rows = cury + (1 if curx == 0 else 0)
```

Since the `addstr` started at the origin, you don't need to call `getyx` twice.  The conditional expression accounts for line-wrapping.